# How to copy the value of one parameter of class to another Collection object?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

```
class ResourceDTO {
      String resourceName;
      List<AssociateResource> associateResource = new ArrayList<AssociateResource>;
      // getter-setter...
}


class AssociateResource {
      String associateName;
      // other attributes...
      // getter-setters...
}
```

Now, I have challenge that whenever `ResourceDTO` get populated whatever the resourceName is, associateName will be the same. How should I do this?

Ex:- If a stream is populating `ResourceDTO`, so in list of "AssociateResource" variable "resourceName" should contain same name. How should I do this? Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: if you want to use the same setters and getters make the variable `static` so that you can set a new value or get the previous value

Comment: @BoHalim Sorry, but using **static** doesnt help at all here. Worse, it just makes room for all kinds of sorry, stupid bugs.

Comment: @GhostCat Sorry, maybe I misinterpreted the problem !

Answer (score 1):

Set the name for all associated resources in the setter of `ResourceDTO`:

```
class ResourceDTO {
    // ... 
    public void setResourceName(final String name) {
        this.resourceName = name;
        this.associateResource.forEach(a -> a.setAssociateName(name));
    }
}
```